# ContextSwitchDeadlock The CLR does not perform transition context to context COM

Tags: wpf, clr, deadlock

I am using VS 2010 Ultimate on Windows Vista. 
I am using an WPF application with WCF et Entity framework. 
I currently use Frame work 4.0. In Debug mode I have this exception.

The CLR does not perform transition context to context 0x2aacbb0 COM COM 0x2aace00 for 60 seconds. 
The thread that owns the context / partitioning destination is probably waiting or treat a very long operation without pumping Windows messages. 
This situation generally has a negative effect on performance and can sometimes lead to the blocking of the application or uninterrupted use of the memory. 
To avoid this problem, all the threads STA (Single Threaded Apartment) should use pumping wait primitives (such CoWaitForMultipleHandles) and pump regularly posts during operations which are long to run. 
(Translated from French)

any help appreciated

Comment: Possible duplicate of [.NET - ContextSwitchDeadlock was detected](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8106159/net-contextswitchdeadlock-was-detected/8106274#8106274).

Answer (score 0):

This is probably because your main thread or UI thread is blocked by a long computing operation. Interaction with DB on the UI thread or other computations are responsible for this issue. Possibly your code violates the basic STA principles.